# Migrate dbms_crypto encrypted data from oracle to PostgreSQL

Tags: database-migration, postgresql-10, dbms-crypto

I want to migrate some of the tables with encrypted columns from oracle to postgres.
 In oracle, data is encrypted uding dbms_crypto. 
I am thinking that I will encrypt data in postgreSQL using pgp keys.
My question is -
1. Do I need to decrypt the data in oracle then migrate to postgres and encrypt again. 
2. Or Is there way that I export encrypted data from oracle and apply same algorithm in postgres to decrypt.

How to do it.